# Herokuでnode.jsのリモートデバッグはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: node.js, heroku

HerokuにWebDynoとして起動したnode.jsのアプリをリモートデバッグするためにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

```
web: port=$PORT node --debug=5858 index.js
```

このようにProcfileを設定して起動したところ、443のみtelnetで接続可能で、5858は接続できませんでした。
そもそも、WebDynoの場合はdebug portを開けて接続すること自体できないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

デフォルトでは80と443以外のポートは開放されてないかと思いますので、おそらく出来ないのでは無いかと。
もしくは[この記事](https://jkutner.github.io/2015/05/19/heroku-remote-debug-java.html)のようにNGROKのようなプロキシをはさめば出来るかもしれません。